# Цикл асинхронных запросов, как лучше реализовать?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Как лучше организовать асинхронный код с запросом в цикле, вынести цикл в отдельный метод и вызвать его асинхронно из основного потока или цикл оставить в основном потоке, а просто запрос сделать асинхронным?

Comment: Ну, async/await обычно лучше. Но чтобы мы не гадали, что в чёрном ящике, покажите ваш код.

Comment: Кода пока нет, поэтому я и хочу разобраться сначала!

Comment: Ну, покамест ваш вопрос выглядит как-то так: «Я собираюсь написать два куска кода, какой из них будет лучше?» Правильный ответ: «А откуда нам знать?»

Comment: А где и зачем у вас цикл?

Comment: я загружаю список юзеров с сайта, чтоб получить полный список мне необходимо последовательно в цикле делать множество запросов, в ответ я получаю порции юзеров, из которых в итоге собирается один файл. Я хочу эту генерацию файла запустить отдельно от основного потока, чтоб интерфейс продолжал быть активным.

Comment: Таки VladD тогда прав и проще чисто запрос к сайту через async\await делать, если больше там логики нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы делаете просто запросы к сайту, и записываете результат в файл, имеет смысл не возиться с многопоточностью, а применять асинхронные функции. У вас должно получиться что-то такое:

```
async Task ReadAndWrite()
{
    var http = new HttpClient();
    using (var outStream = File.Create(path))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var uri = string.Format(uriPattern, i);
            string s = await GetPartInformation(http, i);
            var info = ExtractInfo(s);
            byte[] bytes = ConverToBytes(info);
            await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}

const string uriPattern = "http://example.org/get/{0}";
async Task<string> GetPartInformation(HttpClient http, int i)
{
    var uri = string.Format(uriPattern, i);
    byte[] information;
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        using (var content = response.Content)
            return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

---

Этот код можно улучшать. Например, простое улучшение — не ждать окончания записи, и приступать к дальнейшему чтению.

```
async Task ReadAndWrite()
{
    Task pendingWriteTask = null;
    var http = new HttpClient();
    using (var outStream = File.Create(path))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var uri = string.Format(uriPattern, i);
            string s = await GetPartInformation(http, i);
            var info = ExtractInfo(s);
            byte[] bytes = ConvertToBytes(info);
            if (pendingWriteTask != null)
                await pendingWriteTask;
            pendingWriteTask = stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        if (pendingWriteTask != null)
            await pendingWriteTask;
    }
}
```

---

Если код `ExtractInfo` и `ConvertToBytes` медленный, его стоит выгрузить из UI-потока при помощи `var info = await Task.Run(() => ExtractInfo(s));` и т. п.

Comment: Это и хотел выяснить. Спасибо

Comment: @BorzTorkoy: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, поможет.